# how to add android platform in phonegap project

Tags: cordova, android-studio, phonegap-desktop-app

I've just started working with phonegap and android studio, I'm totally beginner
I made my first project in phonegap, now I want to add it into android studio, for that purpose I must first add android platform in phonegap project, can someone tell me how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Add Platforms](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/#add-platforms).

```
$ cordova platform add android --save
```

If you have the phonegap cli installed instead, replace `cordova` with `phonegap`.

Comment: It doesn't work! isn't anyway to do this without terminal?

Comment: How did you create your project?

Comment: I just opened phonegap app v0.4.3, clicked on create new project and then edited index.html file in the www directory

Comment: I don't believe you are able to add platforms through the desktop app. Install the command line interface http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/cli/ then open your projects folder in terminal and run that command